# How to trim minutes and hours and seconds from Date object?

Tags: java, date

I need to make map where Dates are keys. 2 date objects are equals if they have the same value of `getTime()` method.

I'm interested only in year, month and day. How can I `trim` unnecessary hours and minutes to get 'clear' dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom `Comparator<Date>` for a `TreeMap<Date,V>`.

```
    Comparator<Date> ymdComparator = new Comparator<Date>() {
        @Override public int compare(Date d1, Date d2) {
            return 
                d1.getYear() < d2.getYear() ? -1 :
                d1.getYear() > d2.getYear() ? +1 :
                d1.getMonth() < d2.getMonth() ? -1 :
                d1.getMonth() > d2.getMonth() ? +1 :
                d1.getDay() < d2.getDay() ? -1 :
                d1.getDay() > d2.getDay() ? +1 :
                0;
        }
    };

    SortedMap<Date,V> map = new TreeMap<Date,V>(ymdComparator);
```

Oh, [`java.util.Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) sucks, use Joda Time, etc.

Comment: +1 for comparator, -1 for deprecated methods, +1 for suckage.

Comment: I used DateUtils.isSameDay(d1, d2) from commons-lang inside my comparator instead of all these ternary operators.

Answer (score 24):

You can create a `trim` method:

```
public static Date trim(Date date) {
      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.clear(); // as per BalusC comment.
      cal.setTime( date );
      cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
      return cal.getTime();
 }
```

And use it like:

```
 map.put( trim( aDate ), xyz() );
```

...

```
 map.get( trim( otherDate ));
```

Here's a complete working sample:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import static java.util.Calendar.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;


public class DateTest {
    public static void main( String [] args )  throws InterruptedException {
            Date date = new Date();
            Thread.sleep(1);
            Date other = new Date();
            out.printf("equals? = %s, hashCode? = %s %n", (date.equals(other)), (date.hashCode() == other.hashCode()));

            Date todayeOne = trim( date );
            Date todayTwo  = trim( date );


            out.printf("equals? = %s, hashCode? = %s %n", (todayeOne.equals(todayTwo)), (todayeOne.hashCode() == todayTwo.hashCode()));

    }

    public static Date trim(Date date) {
          Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
          cal.setTime( date );
          cal.set(HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
          cal.set(MINUTE, 0);
          cal.set(SECOND, 0);
          cal.set(MILLISECOND, 0);
          return cal.getTime();
     }

}
```

output:

```
$ java DateTest 
equals? = false, hashCode? = false 
equals? = true, hashCode? = true
```

Comment: I'd add a `clear()` before `setTime()` to avoid timezone issues. OT: Account merge? It was high time :)

Comment: @BalusC added. Yep, I had two 10k accounts already so, I though a merge was in order.

Comment: @BalusC i don't understand the need for clear()?  doesn't setTime() reset everything?

Comment: @james: it's a "practice" which was teached me years ago. The calendar was previously littered of bugs of which most was fixed by explicitly calling `clear()` after `getInstance()`. It also depends on JVM used.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate ld =
    myUtilDate.toInstant()
              .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
              .toLocalDate();
```

## Details

The Question and other Answers use outmoded old date-time classes that have proven to be poorly-designed, confusing, and troublesome. Now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

### `Instant` truncated

To more directly address the question:

1. Convert to java.time, from `java.util.Date` to `java.time.Instant`.
2. Truncate to the date.

Convert via new methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

The truncation feature is built into the `Instant` class. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instantTruncated = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.DAYS );
```

### `ZonedDateTime` & `LocalDate`

But the approach above has issues. Both `java.util.Date` and `Instant` represent a moment on the timeline in UTC rather than an particular time zone. So if you drop the time-of-day, or set it to `00:00:00`, you are getting a date that only makes sense in UTC. If you meant the date for Auckland NZ or Montréal Québec, you may have the wrong date.

So a better approach is to apply your desired/expected time zone to the `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Another problem is that we are inappropriately using a date-time object to represent a date-only value. Instead we should use a date-only class. From the `ZonedDateTime` we should extract a `LocalDate` if all you want is the date-only.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
long time1 = myDate1.getTime()/(1000*60*60*24);
long time2 = myDate2.getTime()/(1000*60*60*24);
if (time1 == time2)
    // equal!
```

This pushes insignificant values below the decimal, then integer division truncates it, so only values significant at the Day level and higher are left.

If you want to make those dates again, just apply the offset back to the truncated values:

```
myDate1.setTime(time1 * (1000*60*60*24));
myDate2.setTime(time2 * (1000*60*60*24));
```

Comment: This solution is subtly wrong because it does not take TimeZone offset into account. For example, 21 May 0:35 UTC+1 gets converted to 20 May 1:00 UTC+1.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your `Date` objects to be equal, if the have the same year, month and day:

```
public static Date convertDate(Date oldDate) {
    final long oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    long newDate = oldDate.getTime() / oneDay;
    return new Date( newDate * oneDay );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Proposed solution does not work in Android as it is stuck on Java 7 and so Calendar is buggy. Others solutions also had bugs because they did not take into account TimeZone offset, or have problems with int overflow before they get converted to long.

This solution seems to work:

```
public static final long MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY=(1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L);

public static long convertDate(Date d) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    long val = d.getTime() + tz.getOffset(d.getTime()); /*local timezone offset in ms*/
    return val / MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY;
}

public static Date convertDate(long date) {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Date d=new Date();
    d.setTime(date*MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY-tz.getOffset(d.getTime()));
    return d;
}
```